# Obtener el id de una consulta en jquery Api Rest

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, api

Tengo este script de jquery que trae un json alojado en una api rest

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/api_megacable/cable",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(index, data){
                    $("#television").append("<td>id:"+data.id+"<input type='radio' class='rbtelevision' value='"+data.id+"'></td>");
                })
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error al cargar el carusel");
                console.log(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("failure");
                console.log(response);
            }
    });
$("#registro").click(function(){
        alert("has hecho click");
        var television = $(".rbtelevision").val();
        console.log(television);
    });

});
```

arroja este json

```
[{"id":"3","nombre":"Basico Plus Digital","numero_canales":"135","numero_musica":"50","precio":null},{"id":"4","nombre":"Basico Digital + HD Total","numero_canales":"190","numero_musica":"50","precio":null},{"id":"6","nombre":"Basico Digital","numero_canales":"119","numero_musica":"50","precio":null}]
```

[image: Vista]

En la vista no importa cual valor seleccione siempre me arroja el primer valor osea el 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen 2 errores:

- Estas usando el selector `.rbtelevision`, el cual esta asociado a 3 elementos y el método `.val()`, solo devuelve el valor del primero.
- A los `input radio` no les estas asignando un `name`, lo que provoca que puedas seleccionar mas de uno.

Solución:

- Usar el pseudo clase [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) para obtener solamente el `input` chequeado.

  ```
  $("#registro").click(function(){
    var television = $(".rbtelevision:checked").val();
    console.log(television);
  });
  ```
- Asignar, por ejemplo `name='television'`, a los `input`.

  ```
  $.each(data, function(index, info){
    $("#television").append("<td>id:"+info.id+"<input type='radio' name='television' class='rbtelevision' value='"+info.id+"'></td>");
  });
  ```

Demo:

```js
var data = [{"id":"3","nombre":"Basico Plus Digital","numero_canales":"135","numero_musica":"50","precio":null},{"id":"4","nombre":"Basico Digital + HD Total","numero_canales":"190","numero_musica":"50","precio":null},{"id":"6","nombre":"Basico Digital","numero_canales":"119","numero_musica":"50","precio":null}];

$.each(data, function(index, info){
  $("#television").append("<td>id:"+info.id+"<input type='radio' name='television' class='rbtelevision' value='"+info.id+"'></td>");
});

$("#registro").click(function(){
  var television = $(".rbtelevision:checked").val();
  console.log(television);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="television"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="registro">Registro</button>
```